# regex to match their, their's, theirs, theirs, and theirs'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match their and the possessive forms of their with a regex in javascript

So far I have `their|their(?:'?s)`, which matches their, theirs, and their's; but, not theirs'.

How can I do this?

so, `their`, `theirs`,  `their's`, and `theirs'` should match.

Since `theirs` and `their` and `theirs'` and similar, it should match the longer ones. So if the word is `theirs'` it should match that and not just `their` `theirs`

what about `his`, `his'`, `his's`, `his` and not hiss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Optimizing the Regex**

The starting point is this:

```
their|theirs|their's|theirs'
```

Optimized, this would give you:

```
their(?:s'|'?s)?
```

or

```
their(?:s'?|'s)?
```

See [demo 1](http://regex101.com/r/oY8cZ2/1) and [demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/oY8cZ2/2).

**Part 2: his|his'|his's and not hiss**

```
his(?:'s?)?(?!s)
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/jC6tF5/1).

Comment: @zx81 this regex tester ( http://www.regexr.com/ ) says it doesn't match `his'`... it looks like it does though.

Comment: you could use word boundary also `\bhis(?:'s?)?\b`

Comment: @AvinashRaj A boundary will not work... That's why Fede's answer is broken. A boundary will not match on the right side of `'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj still deosn't match `his'` according to regexr.com

Comment: @user3743069 What do you mean? Here is a [regexr demo](http://regexr.com/392u7), my regex does match. :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj No, mate. Look at your demo... `his'` doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this,

```
their\'?s?\'?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tM4wM6/2)

Comment: That would match `their''` as well.